# JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize : PascalCase to CamelCase

Tags: javascript, c#, serialization, camelcasing, pascalcasing

I have this javascript object

```
var options:
 {
        windowTitle         : '....',
        windowContentUrl    : '....',
        windowHeight        : 380,
        windowWidth         : 480
}
```

And I have this C# class

```
public class JsonDialogViewModel
    {
        public string WindowTitle               {   get;    set;    }
        public string WindowContentUrl          {   get;    set;    }
        public double WindowHeight              {   get;    set;    }
        public double WindowWidth               {   get;    set;    }

    }
```

And you see, my notation is PascalCase in C# and my Javascript is CamelCase.
That the usual convention.

I am using **JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize** to serialize my C# object and use it in my Javascript code.

I am however facing this issue of PascalCase to CamelCase that JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize does not handle.

What do you suggest to get around this translation?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The best solution I could find was to have a method that receives the object to be serialized, generates a `Dictionary<string, object>` based on the properties of the object and then apply `JavaScriptSerializer.Serialize()` to this Dictionary.
This was good enough for what I needed.